# How to remove Laravel Auth Hashing (to replace it by mysql hashing)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I added registration, and I don't want to using laravels hash but mysql Hash (because I want existing users to still be able to connect).
So i do it step by step and for now I just try to register and then login without any hashing. The credentials are correct in my table but I get 
"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["These credentials do not match our records."]}

I tried setting it in LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function password()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = $password;
    }

    public function Login(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'pwd' => $request->password, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
          $user = Auth::user();
          $username = $user->nom;
          return response()->json([
            'status'   => 'success',
            'user' => $username,
          ]); 
        } else { 
          return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'user'   => 'Unauthorized Access'
          ]); 
        } 
    }

}
```

I guess I should overwrite another function, but can't find out which one.
Could you please give me some help?

Comment: You have to override methods of login and forgot password all your function to the app/http/controller folder

Comment: Auth::attempt() internally hash the password

Comment: I have initially done this kind of change and used md5() for password encryption

Comment: Thanks, so how can I remove hashing from Auth::attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough what you're trying to achieve is considered unsecure, to remove Laravel's hashing for password, you need to add this to your `User` model :

```php
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
    $this->attributes['password'] = $password;
}
```

and not in your controller, and be sure to remove the `brcypt()` methods in your `RegisterController`

---

To add your MySQL own hashing methods, update your controller to insert a RAW query while creating a user upon registration

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had added setPasswordAttribute in LoginController instead...As I said, it was just a "first step" and I want to add Hashing, but as the datatable already does exist, I can't add Laravel's hashing.